# cannot access my local network address

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking

Recently i moved to the new apartment where i already found working and running router with internet access.

Lets say i have node.js app running from my own Mac PC on port `3000`. previously i could access that app by typing:

- `localhost:3000`
- `192.168.1.120:3000`

both methods worked and i also could access this app from different PC connected to the same network

Now i can only access it by typing `localhost:3000`, while my current local address `192.168.1.4:3000` returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I didnt change anything aside from apartment which is just router and ISP. What can be wrong?

Comment: Two things I can think of - (A) your macOS might have some firewall configuration that was allowing connections to the old address but they didn't translate over to the new address; or (B) your app is not binding to the new IP address - if that's the case, it should be obvious from the app configuration. What address is your app binding to?

Comment: app isnt bound to any specific address, only to port `server.listen(port);` and its by default like this, in docs it says: "Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.", however what i discovered is that if i specifiy `localhost` or `192...` it works on one or the other, while if i say `0.0.0.0` it works on both. The question is, why i need to specify `0.0.0.0` to achieve what previously was happening by default?

Comment: Is there a difference in IPv6 support between your old and new networks? According to the node.js API, "if host is omitted, the server will accept connections to IPv6 (::) when IPv6 is available, or IPv4 (0.0.0.0) otherwise". Sounds like there's room there for it to only listen on IPv6, not IPv4. But when you specify 0.0.0.0 as the listen host, it'll bind specifically to all IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new/old router probably does not support loopback out of the computer and back again.

Referencing `localhost` goes via a specialized interface and not through the router,
so is not affected.